Pandas Unable to Find NaN when 0 is divided by 0
I have dataframe like this:
df_challenge = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, pd.NA, 6, 9, pd.NA, 0, 9, 10, 0, 9, pd.NA, 0],
                                 'y': [0, 7.2, pd.NA, 10, 0, 1, 9.2, 10.65, pd.NA, 9, pd.NA, 0],
                                  'y_copy': [0, 7.2, np.nan, 10, 0, 1, 9.2, 10.65, np.nan, 9, np.nan,0]})

df_challenge = df_challenge.convert_dtypes()

I forcefully changed the type of one of the columns
df_challenge.y_copy = df_challenge.y_copy.astype('float')

I now create two variables using below code:
df_challenge = df_challenge.assign(z = df_challenge.x/df_challenge.y)
df_challenge = df_challenge.assign(z1 = df_challenge.x.astype('float')/df_challenge.y_copy)

Now, If I try .isnull() method or .isna() method of series, it doesn't show correct result for column z
The below code gives these results:
df_challenge.z.isna().sum() # 5 It should be 6
df_challenge.z.isnull().sum() # 5 

df_challenge.z1.isna().sum() # 6 It is correct
df_challenge.z1.isnull().sum() # 6 

My question is, why the .isnull() or .isna() isn't performing correctly (or I am mistaken here) in these columns. The difference is that the data types involved in calculation are different, in z (division is happening on two (Int64/Float64, pandas newer datatypes), However in z1 calculation(division is happening on two floats)
Now, to circumvent the problem instead of using .isna, .isnull I have tried np.isfinite with pandas (not operator ~) and it correctly figures out NAN in z1
So, my second question is that whether this is a good idea to pull such NANs in pandas
Here is what worked
df_challenge.loc[~df_challenge.z.pipe(np.isfinite),:]

However, I am not satisfied with this workaround, although to me this works. But I wanted to understand this and thinking of a better solution.
Thanks

Pandas version: '2.2.2'
Python version: Python 3.10.14

1/0 is infinite (+inf), so a number according floating point convention of IEEE 754. numpy (and pandas) uses C convention. instead Python division give a division by zero. On large data, it is better to keep CPU (FPU) rules, not to add additional calculations and check for every cell.
You may get more information in:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic , in particular history and other sections may gives you an idea why some conventions was put (and when).
Why? More information is better. with NaN we may discard the value, because incomplete dataset, but infinite gives us a different error: we have some logic problem, which we may handle differently, so better not to discard silently.
There is no right solution, at the end, somebody choose a convention (maybe different one in each project e.g. IEEEE 754, C, python, numpy), which may not be ideal for one uses case, but also the alternative have problem (on other use cases). And do not worry, usually all such decision where not taken lightly, or without huge discussions. In fact Python changed twice the meaning of division of integers (Python 1 to Python 2, and later reverted in Python 3), and still module operator may gives surprises (with negative numbers)

Thanks you for your response. I get what you are saying, The only thing is that , the NaN returned by division by Int64/Float64 looks very similar (representation wise) when we do float/float, so as a user one can easily get confused. My only concern is that it should be consistent with datatypes, which seems its not for now or may be I am mistaken here
